# What is "init and unseal workflow"

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I'm looking at the differences between the different versions of Vault.   The chart at the bottom of https://www.hashicorp.com/products/vault/ mentions that the open source version does not have something called "init and unseal workflow".  I have tried searching for that phrase in the documentation and can't find anything.  What functionality does that mean that it is missing?  Do new instances not start off sealed/etc?

Thanks,
Heath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vault [init and seal workflow](http://www.marketwired.com/press-release/hashicorp-announces-general-availability-vault-enterprise-devops-security-across-dynamic-2156343.htm) is

> an intuitive workflow for initializing new Vault clusters, distributing key shares, and managing the unseal process across a team.

Seal/unseal functionality is available in any version of Vault, as this is one of the basic its concept: without unsealing you do not have a decryption key -> so you cannot decrypt data -> so you cannot access data. Or, in terms of Vault, this is a [sealed state](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/seal.html).

In open source version, after you do `vault init` you get a list of unseal keys and the root token. After that, it is up to you where and how to store keys, or share those keys with other team members, etc... But you need to provide keys when you need to do `unseal` for your Vault server (for example after server restart, as server will be again in sealed state). And Vault does not help you with that, it only expect that keys will be provided during unsealing.

Comment: Thanks.  It turns out that the open source version IS what I have been playing with so far.  (I thought we had a trial version of one of the paid versions.)  So I am aware of the steps you have to take to get a server up and going with the free version.  If I'm reading your answer right, the "workflow" in the paid versions basically just makes that easier.